# Delayed action in an alert in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, alert, dispatch

Is it possible to have an option to have a delayed action after pressing an alert button?

I've tried to write the code like this:

```
 .alert(isPresented: $showingFeedback) {
                Alert(title: Text(scoreTitle), message:
                        Text(selectedQuestion!.feedback),
                        primaryButton:

                       .dispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .no () + 0.5) {
                       nextQuestion()},
                        
             
                      secondaryButton: .default(Text("Continue")) {
                        nextQuestion()}
                      
                )
            }
```

However when I try run it I get the following error next to the View:

> 'Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please file a bug report'

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60924480/12299030?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that there's no such `Alert.Button` like `.dispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .no () + 0.5)`.

Instead you can use a `.default` button and put the `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` part as an *action* (as suggested by Asperi in the comments):

```
.alert(isPresented: $showingFeedback) {
    Alert(
        title: Text(scoreTitle),
        message: Text(selectedQuestion!.feedback),
        primaryButton: .default(Text("Next")) {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                nextQuestion()
            }
        },
        secondaryButton: .default(Text("Continue")) {
            nextQuestion()
        }
    )
}
```

For clarity you may also extract actions to another functions:

```
.alert(isPresented: $showingFeedback) {
    Alert(
        title: Text(scoreTitle),
        message: Text(selectedQuestion!.feedback),
        primaryButton: .default(Text("Next"), action: nextTapped),
        secondaryButton: .default(Text("Continue"), action: continueTapped)
    )
}
```

```
func nextTapped() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
        nextQuestion()
    }
}

func continueTapped() {
    nextQuestion()
}
```

---

**Note:** it's a good practice to avoid force-unwrapping: instead of:

```
selectedQuestion!.feedback
```

you could do:

```
selectedQuestion?.feedback ?? "some default value"
```

Comment: thank you that did the trick, also thank you for the advice.  Was wondering if you have some more advice - I'm finding that when I press the PrimaryButton the action continues to the next question, is there a way to make it only action once until the button is pressed again?

Comment: @Jon If you have a new question I suggest you create a new post and describe your issue. I'll try to help you there.